# run common gradle code in android base project gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, shared, configure

i have a library which uses all of our apps.
except for shared code and resources i wanted to share gradle code.
each app is constructed:
some_app/
 |
  - settings.gradle
  - build.gradle
 |
  - mylib/
     |
      -build.gradle
  - other_lib/
  - app/
     |
       - build.gradle

right now i'm talking about the build.gradle in the root dir. The one that defines buildScript closure with dependecies and  allprojects{} closure as well.

i tried to use apply from: './mylib/gradle_files/baseProject.gradle'
it works, but then my app can't find the android plugin. for some reason the classpath dependencies were not injected into the build script!
i then tried to create a list and use that:

```
ext.projectBaseDependencies = ['com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2', 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0']
```

I then used the list in my closure:

```
apply from: './mylib/gradle_files/baseProject.gradle'
```

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath projectBaseDependencies
    }
}

it doesn't work, gradle does not find my variable defined in baseProject.gradle.
I have a hunch that apply from works AFTER buildScript closure is evaluated :-(

Is there any way to share gradle script code across ALL apps ? if not apply from, what CAN work ? skip configuration and config in afterEvaluate {} clause ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Gradle file in your common library? If your common library includes a `build.gradle` file, you can apply the android library plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        consumerProguardFiles "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Your common dependencies here
}
```

Then you can include the library in your project's `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':mobile'
project(':common').projectDir = new File("/Users/example/path/to/common")
```

Then add it to your dependencies in the project's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
    // Your other project dependencies
}
```

Comment: this does now allow share properties of the buildscript itself, for the gradle file ofthe application and the gradle file of the libraries i have no problem to use 'apply from:' it's just in the root build,gadle file and the bildScript{} closure